# Custom Media provider

Tags: android, media, media-player, provider

I am trying to create a new mediaprovider for my music app in android .In that I need to map one song with multiple album,artist,genre and so on.Is there any possibility to change it according to my need.Is there any sample code available for the customization of media database.

Comment: By using content provider you can do this.